# Unable to consolidate NuGet package transitive dependency versions in two NET Standard projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework-core, prism, unity-container

**Adding EF Core to a NET Standard project introduces transitive dependency versions incompatible with NuGet packages in other projects**

I have a solution with multiple .NET Standard 2.0 projects.

One **Project A** uses the `Google.Protobuf (3.11.2)` NuGet package, that depends on

```
System.Memory (4.5.3)
    System.Buffers (4.4.0)
    System.Numerics.Vectors (4.4.0)
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe (4.5.2)
```

A few other projects also depend on `System.Memory` and **all use the same dependency versions**.

Another **Project B** uses `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (3.1.0)` NuGet package that depends on

```
System.Memory (4.5.3)
    System.Buffers (4.5.0)
    System.Numerics.Vectors (4.5.0)
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe (4.7.0)
```

Even though the `System.Memory` version is (4.5.3) in both cases, it depends on `System.Buffers`, `System.Numerics.Vectors` and `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` and their versions differ.

When I run the application that uses these projects (a Microsoft Prism WPF .NET Framework 4.8 app that uses Unity IoC) UnityContainer throws the following exception:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.

After searching for a solution I added this to my NuGet.Config:

```
  <config>
    <add key="DependencyVersion" value="Highest" />
  </config>
```

In both, `%appdata%\Nuget` and in the root folder of the `.sln` file.

I also deleted the `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages` folder.

Then I removed the NuGet packages from the projects and added them back again, but their dependecies come with the same versions as before.

If I navigate to "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution..." in Visual Studio and choose "Consolidate" it just says "No packages found"

Comment: Do you mean you have two SAME versions of System.Memory depending on different package versions??

Comment: @PabloRecalde Yes, that is exactly what I mean. But I didn't install `System.Memory` so I can't control its version - it was installed as a dependency of `Google.Protobuf` and of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`

Comment: Seems like Microsoft messed up with versions ... It does not make any sense to me

Comment: As a workarround you can try to overwrite the dll that does not match with others on the .nuget cache folder

Comment: @PabloRecalde If I add the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` package to the project that uses `Google.Protobuf`, then the transitive dependencies of the `Google.Protobuf` change to be the same as with `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` - my guess is that NuGet selects the lowest common version. Of course that is not a solution because I don't want the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` package in the project using `Google.Protobuf`.

Comment: `.net standard` should not reference `.net core` packages. It shoould not have to either. Microsoft created `.net standard` as a bridge to be able to share logic between them. With `.net 5` https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/. If you want to read more about referencing i have provided an answer to this post with elaborate info about minimizing dependency errors -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/59445495/3902958. I am not sure i get 100% what you say, but hope this helps.

Comment: @panoskarajohn my .net standard projects do NOT reference .net core packages - `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` is a .net standard library ;) you can easily reproduce my problem in 3 minutes, if you don't believe me :)

Comment: First off, did only skim. Second, haven't tried to reproduce. Anyway, here goes. Can you maybe solve your problem with a binding redirect? I have one in one of my projects, albeit autogenerated: `<dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="protobuf-net" publicKeyToken="257b51d87d2e4d67" culture="neutral" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.3.2.0" newVersion="2.3.2.0" /></dependentAssembly>` Binding redirects have also caused me trouble and simply deleting them has eliminated problems, too.

Comment: @Heki my solution has 54 projects that reference 43 NuGet packages - each of those packages has somewhere from 5 to 20 transitive dependencies... far too many to write binding redirects by hand (the senior developer and the project manager in my company don't approve this, because it makes the solution hard to maintain) can I get auto generated binding redirects? - there is another solution that can be written by hand: using a json file: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5887

Comment: @Jinjinov If redirects will solve the problem, then automatic generation looks like it will require a bit of work cause updating web.config is not standard. Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48970018/why-doesnt-autogeneratebindingredirects-work-for-a-web-config-in-visual-studio

Comment: @Heki I have tried this solution, but it doesn't work - it appears that <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects> doesn't work for class libraries - here is an open issue: https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/issues/1310

Comment: @Jinjinov Oh, that's a bummer. Last idea: https://blog.yaakov.online/automatically-generating-assembly-binding-redirects/ I hope that will get you going as it specifically mentions class libraries in the bottom. If not, sorry I couldn't help and I hope you reach a solution soon! :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I managed to reproduce the problem.
I created two new `.net standard 2.0 project` class libraries.

On the first I added `EF Core`.
On the second I added `Google protobuf`.

Both same versions as you mention.

For EF core I created a new class that just inherits from `DbContext`.
For Protobuf I just created an empty class as I am not familiar on how to use it.
I was still able to replicate the problem though.

Then I created a `console app .net framework 4.7.2` referencing the above two projects.

I instantiated the two classes in the Console App and got `error System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly...`

### How I resolved it

I went to **all three** projects and added this line to the `csproj`.

`<RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>`

to the Property Group.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
</PropertyGroup>
```

After that I built and ran again and no error appeared.

**Please let me know your results.
Even if my solution does not work for you, I believe it is good practice to have it.**

> To quote Oren.
> "Using .NET Standard requires you to use PackageReference to eliminate the pain of “lots of packages” as well as properly handle transitive dependencies. While you may be able to use .NET Standard without PackageReference, I wouldn’t recommend it."

> Also Hanselman mentions:
> "The "full" Framework projects are using the older .csproj format and by default, they use package.config to manage dependencies. The newer projects can reference Packages as first-class references. So we need to tell ALL projects in this solution to manage and restore their packages as "PackageReferences.""

Here are my sources.

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReferencingNETStandardAssembliesFromBothNETCoreAndNETFramework.aspx

https://oren.codes/2017/04/23/using-xamarin-forms-with-net-standard-vs-2017-edition/

Updated according to Sommen's extra info from the [github issues](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/31)
Kudos to [Sommen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4122889/sommmen) for providing this extra info. Also Kudos to [Immo Landwerth](https://github.com/terrajobst) for providing this Info at GitHub.
I will provide as is the Workarounds that already exist in the Github page just for complecity as advised by the OP jinjinov.

Taken from [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/31)

### Workarounds

#### Regular .NET Framework projects

1. Enable [automatic binding redirects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/how-to-enable-and-disable-automatic-binding-redirection) in the root .NET Framework application
2. Make sure your root application project doesn't use `packages.config` but uses `PackageReference` for NuGet packages:

   - If you currently don't have `packages.config`, simply add
     `<RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>`.
   - If you currently do have a `packages.config`, convert the contents to package references in the project file. The syntax is like this:
     `<PackageReference Include="package-id" Version="package-version" />`

#### ASP.NET web applications and web sites

1. Web applications and web sites don't support automatic binding redirect generation. In order to resolve binding conflicts, you need to double click the warning in the error list and Visual Studio will add them to your web.config file
2. In web application projects, you should enable PackageReference like mentioned above. In web sites, you cannot use PackageReference as there is no project file. In that case, you need to install all NuGet packages into your web site that any of the direct or indirect project references depend on.

#### Unit test projects

By default, binding redirects aren't added to class library projects. This is problematic for unit testing projects as they are essentially like apps. So in addition to what's outlined in [automatic binding redirects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/how-to-enable-and-disable-automatic-binding-redirection) you also need to specify `GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType`:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

There is also a discussion section that provides more information -> [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/481)

Comment: Thank you! Reading the link from sommmen https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/31 I see that your solution works for projects that don't have any NuGet packages -- on GitHub issue see Workarounds, point 2.  -- I assume that you didn't include any in your console app? If you update your answer to include all worarounds I will accept it, because you wrote it before sommmen did :)

Comment: @Jinjinov thank you, I have updated the answer to provide the full info. If you feel there is more to it. Do not hesitate to edit and update.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning unit tests! My class library with conflicting transitive dependencies worked fine, but the FileLoadException was thrown when running tests from the test project even though the test project did not reference the NuGet packages! I added only GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType to MyTests.csproj, no AutoGenerateBindingRedirects needed.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, welcome to the struggle.

Like PanosKarajohn pointed out using packagereference instead of packages.config helps with this. Unfortunately, that is Vs2017 and up and for some of us that is not yet in sight.

The problem is actually explained pretty much here:
https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/31

You need to use binding redirects to redirect all the version numbers to the highest on you got and then pray that everything plays nice with each other.

I use the Microsoft.aspnetcore.signalR package in a .net 4.6.1 project and you have the same issues.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include your link for complecity as advised by the OP.

Comment: Yep. I actually spent maybe 3 days or so struggling with this issue, especially because we're at a point in time where i need to support vs2015 and vs2019. I actually have a class library which runs a script that creates a {name}.exe.config file to work with all the binding redirects. This then gets copied to the executable project (and we pray all versions are backwards compatible). I Hope we can at some point in time upgrade everything to .net std and core. Congrats on the well-deserved bounty, and hopefully we all learned a lot from this endeavor :)

Comment: Thanks.I certainly did learn a lot.Feel free to edit my answer and append to it :)